# UIPickerView with variable/dependent second column

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am trying to have a UIPickerView where the second column will depend on what's chosen in the first column.

For example:
Suppose the first column has the fruits Apple, Orange, Pear.

If i select Apple in the first column I want the second column to list (Fuji, Granny Smith, Red Delicious). For Orange I want the second column to become (Blood, Navel, Valencia)

How can this be made to work? Also, is it a good idea with regards to Human Interface Guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is

```
reloadComponent
```